# Language Processing -Synonyms Analysis

Tags: nlp, synonym

I'm trying to develop a web app which analyzes a single word and its synonym words happen to shows in a bunch of paragraphs. 
Accumulate how many times the word and its synonyms appear in the paragraphs.

Currently what I find some API such as twinword.com, it only make similarities in two sentences. Any API or services of tools that can complete the task?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using two other Twinword APIs to get what you want.

### STEP 1: Getting Related Words

Using [**Word Associations API**](https://www.twinword.com/api/word-associations.php), you can get synonyms and related words.

For example, using the demo, the word "**best**" returns the following associations and their relevance score to "best":

```
{
    "unmatched": 2.5006557,
    "unparalleled": 1.8664826,
    "incomparable": 1.6736358,
    "unsurpassed": 1.6117903,
    "optimal": 1.576423,
    "supreme": 1.5223511,
    "superbly": 1.4789101,
    "superior": 1.3964652,
    "superiority": 1.3161669,
    "superlative": 1.3032479,
    "matchless": 1.3011634,
    "better": 1.2848812,
    "unrivaled": 1.2450347,
    "foremost": 1.2047551,
    "maximum": 1.1856474,
    "excellent": 1.1767814,
    "heyday": 1.0933546,
    "unpaired": 1.0249922,
    "optimum": 0.9539663,
    "superb": 0.9439568,
    "peerless": 0.92408043,
    "premier": 0.91121525,
    "ideal": 0.85982496,
    "splendid": 0.8591815,
    "nonpareil": 0.85686266,
    "well": 0.85620004,
    "apotheosis": 0.85186666,
    "unequaled": 0.82653475,
    "peak": 0.73392785,
    "main": 0.6999291
}
```

### STEP 2: Reducing Paragraph to Keyword Counts

After that, you can use the [**Lemmatizer API**](https://www.twinword.com/api/lemmatizer.php) to parse your paragraph into an array of "lemmas" or "root words".

```
The frogs hopped from rock to rock.
```

Returns:

```
"lemma": {
    "rock": 2,
    "hop": 1,
    "frog": 1
}
```

### STEP 3: Search and tally within your program

Then, it's just a simple occurrence matching.

FYI: I work for Twinword.

Answer (score 0):

Word2Vec is such a technique. A neural net that transforms a word to a vector, the neural net is trained to group word together according to context.

The idea is that words with similar semantic properties share comparable context in a large body of text. You can use such a model to retrieve similar words.

This is a simple example, using a pre-trained model ([source](https://github.com/clips/dutchembeddings)). Please note that the model is trained for Dutch, which happens to be laying around on my pc (these models can be quite large).

```
>>> from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
>>> word_vectors = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format("320/wikipedia-320.txt", binary=False) 

>>> print(word_vectors.similarity("auto", "auto")) #identity
>>> print(word_vectors.similarity("auto", "wagen")) #synonym
>>> print(word_vectors.similarity("dier", "hond")) #hyponym
>>> print(word_vectors.similarity("kaas", "schrijven")) #unrelated

1.0
0.78154475055  
0.26128426093  
0.0455340792091
```

As you can see the stronger the relation the higher the score

Please check: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html for more documentation

Comment: No problemo. Let me know if you want more detail.

Comment: Hi S van Balen, do you have examples or sample app/api for showing? thanks.

Comment: Sure, I'll add it to the answer

Comment: oh and don't forget to try out this method too: word_vectors.similar_by_word("auto") , this should yield a list of similar words, that sounds like what you are looking for.